# Header creation with the insertion of two figures

Tags: floats, header-footer, covers

I intend to make a header for an academic activity, but it is necessary to insert two figures (one on each side) so that it is in accordance with what was requested by the professor.

In this sense, how do I make this header that allows the insertion of two figures and that the text is between them?

Thank u

[image: Header]

Comment: Hi! Could you please provide us an MWE, so that we can at least know what you've done 'till now? Thanks :D!

Comment: Is this on every page, or just the title page?

Comment: Good that you have posted your question here. But at the same time peers on this forum would be excited to see how far you have progressed in your task, rather than give it to someone to solve from scratch.  More precisely, a minimum working example or [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe) would be highly acknowledged.  That would also hopefully draw in more attention of LaTeX experts to your question-- that you have done so far... and not leave most of your questions unanswered (as they are now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct such a layout using LaTeX boxes.

[image: Header with images alongside]

The code behind this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\makeatletter

\newlength\headerintomargin
\newlength\titlewidth
\newlength\sideimagewidth

\setlength\headerintomargin{2.5cm}
\setlength\titlewidth{0.6\textwidth}

\newcommand{\makeimageheader}{
    \par\newpage\bgroup\noindent
    \global\@topnum=0\relax
    \setlength\sideimagewidth{\dimexpr(\textwidth - \titlewidth)/2 + \headerintomargin\relax}%
    \adjustbox{right=\dimexpr\sideimagewidth-\headerintomargin\relax,valign=T}{%
        \includegraphics[width=\sideimagewidth]{assets/red.png}%
    }%
    \parbox[t]{\titlewidth}{
        \bigskip
        \begin{center}
            \LARGE
            {\scshape

            university\\
            center\\
            department\\}
            \medskip
            \Large\@title
        \end{center}
    }%
    \adjustbox{left=\dimexpr\sideimagewidth-\headerintomargin\relax,valign=T}{%
        \includegraphics[width=\sideimagewidth]{assets/blue.png}%
    }%
    \vspace{20pt}
    \egroup
}

\makeatother

\title{Subject}

\begin{document}
    \makeimageheader

    \tableofcontents
    \section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

This creates three boxes of fixed width. The first for the left image, then one for the centered text, and the third for the right image. Note the images technically 'leak' into the margins.

You need to set `\headerintomargin` to the length of your left and right margins, or an amount less if you don't want the images to go right to the edge. The percent signs in the code prevent unwanted whitespace.

Finally, do you want this automatically on each page, or just once like this? And feel free to ask if you want more detail on what a part of the code is doing!